# youtube's embeded video wont go behind other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I have a site that has YouTube's embedded video in it, my problem is, these videos don't obey the z-index rules. All the YouTube videos are displayed on top of all other elements. I tried

```
$('iframe','.video_container').attr('wmode','opaque');
$('iframe','.video_container').attr('z-index','1');
```

I found that the wmmode has to be changed to opaque, but isn't this for the old embedded videos??
How do i achieve this for both old embedded style videos and the new iframes??

**Edit:**
Even this didn't work on old embedded videos

```
$('object','.video_container').append('<param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>').find("embed").attr('wmode', 'opaque');
```

this works on iframe videos

```
var src=$('iframe','.video_container').attr('src');
 if(src.indexOf('?')==-1)
 {
  src=src+'?wmode=transparent';
 }
 else
 {
  src=src+'&wmode=transparent';
 }
 $('iframe','.video_container').attr('src',src);
```

but i still haven't found a way for old embed videos
This is the resultant code after manipulating using js that doesn't work

```
<object width="320" height="240">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/-SNytfkJD4U?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/-SNytfkJD4U?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="240" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque"/>
<param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
</object>
```

Comment: so if you have used my answer you could have at least voted it up -.- that is not very kind of you, and will probably lead to people not helping you again ..

Comment: sorry about that, i was very worried about it to work. did it now... if you can get the old embed videos work, that can as well serve me as a complete answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var googleFooYou_tube = function(){
    var objs = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    var length = objs.length;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
        if(objs[i].className == 'video_container'){
            var param = document.createElement('param');
            param.name='wmode';
            param.value='transparent';
            var origEmbed = objs[i].getElementsByTagName('embed')[0];
            var newEmbed = '<embed wmode="transparent" src="'+origEmbed.src+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="349" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">';
            objs[i].appendChild(param);
            objs[i].removeChild(origEmbed);
            objs[i].innerHTML=objs[i].innerHTML+newEmbed;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and your html code so far

```
<object width="425" height="349" class="video_container">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/-SNytfkJD4U?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="349" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/-SNytfkJD4U?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
</embed>
</object>
<script>googleFooYou_tube();</script> // added this at the bottom of your page
```

It's not usuable as it is... I mean the function... but you can alter it for your needs... and make it look more appealing if you want.  It is just a quick and dirty approach and it works flawlessly.

Comment: please correct me where am i doing the mistake? http://jsfiddle.net/sasidhar/fBBuL/

Comment: you are doing fine so far, but as far as I know it won't work this way.. once the embed element is there and was rendered, just changing or adding the attribute via jquery will have no effect at all - this is why I have chosen to build a new element, remove the old one and then add the newly created one :)

Comment: then how do i redraw an element? Removing it from the dom and appending it again just doesn't look fine. Any other way?

Comment: in fact I don't know if there is an other way that works in a cross-browser way. if you feel more comfortable, remove the whole element from the dom and insert youtubes iframe solution then :)

Comment: at last......... this seems to work........ http://jsfiddle.net/sasidhar/yXLkt/3/ thanks alot......

Comment: by manipulating the innerHTML, the browser believes that the innerHTML has changes and will redraw the element.

Answer (score 6):

just alter your iframe src like this

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/UUeRCDyVspR2M?wmode=transparent
```

so the flashplayer served by google will render like you told em with that parameter :)

you simply have to add ?wmode=transparent to the params or do it like this

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/UUeRCDyVspR2M?param1=bla&param2=foo&and_so_on=more&wmode=transparent
```

so you simply have to append

```
&wmode=transparent
```

to the end of the url

Comment: how do i do that without messing with other get parameters of the url??

Comment: What about the previous embed videos? the other answer doesn't work

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by previous embed videos..

I guess you need to add it to them too! But actually I don't exactly know what you mean ..

Comment: For codes like these `<object width="425" height="349"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/-SNytfkJD4U?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/-SNytfkJD4U?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="349" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>`

Comment: yea, will post an answer when i am home, don't worry - just hold on for about 45 minutes ;)

Comment: thats the real answer to this question i think.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a param for `wmode` in the flash element which will be an object tag in your markup. Try to find the object element and try this

```
$('object','.video_container').append(
    $("<param/>").attr({
        'name': 'wmode',
        'value': 'opaque'
    })
).find("embed").attr('wmode', 'opaque');
```

Comment: it is in an iframe, isn't it? so he can't change values in an iframe that has its source outside his domain ;)

Comment: @sasidhar - Is your flash video inside an iframe?

Comment: The new embed code that youtube provides is an iframe like this `<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-SNytfkJD4U?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: If you are using the iframe route then this will not work, may be you can try `http://www.youtube.com/embed/-SNytfkJD4U?rel=0&wmode=opaque` as the source of iframe

Comment: There goes +1 for you @Walialu :)